# Turn a HTML image element into a base64 image whilst adopting the inline width and height

Tags: angular, cropper

I'm using `ng2-img-cropper` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-img-cropper). It provides settings so that when a file is selected from an input, it applies a base64 url to an image tag in the HTML whilst adopting 'cropperSettings', such as a defined width and height.

However, I have a requirement where by I need to have two images produced instead of one. A large image and a small image. The large image will be 500x500, whilst the small image will be 200x200. I have created two 'cropperSettings' so that the HTML inline widths and heights show both sizes. However, the src attribute is still the same for both. In this case, they are both 500x500.

Is it possible with javascript to grab a html img element (which has base64 as the src attribute) and turn it into a base64 image but using the inline height and width, opposed to the src image height and width? (In this case, the 3rd image tag below - Using the smaller settings for height and width)

**HTML**

```
<img-cropper #cropper [image]="data1" [settings]="cropperSettings1"></img-cropper>
<img id="largeImage" [src]="data1.image" [width]="cropperSettings1.croppedWidth" [height]="cropperSettings1.croppedHeight">
<img id="thumbnailImage" [src]="data1.image" [width]="cropperSettings2.croppedWidth" [height]="cropperSettings2.croppedHeight">
```

**Cropper Settings**

```
// This is for the large image (500x500)
this.cropperSettings1 = new CropperSettings();
this.cropperSettings1.width = 200;
this.cropperSettings1.height = 200;
this.cropperSettings1.croppedWidth = 500;
this.cropperSettings1.croppedHeight = 500;
this.cropperSettings1.canvasWidth = 500;
this.cropperSettings1.canvasHeight = 500;
this.cropperSettings1.minWidth = 500;
this.cropperSettings1.minHeight = 500;
this.cropperSettings1.rounded = false;
this.cropperSettings1.cropperDrawSettings.strokeColor = 'rgba(255,255,255,1)';
this.cropperSettings1.cropperDrawSettings.strokeWidth = 2;
this.cropperSettings1.noFileInput = true;
this.cropperSettings1.keepAspect = true;
this.data1 = {};

// This is for the small image
this.cropperSettings2 = new CropperSettings();
this.cropperSettings2.croppedWidth = 200;
this.cropperSettings2.croppedHeight = 200;
```

**Function fired when a file is detected**

```
var image: any = new Image();
  var file: File = event.target.files[0];
  var myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
  var that = this;
  myReader.onloadend = (loadEvent: any) => {
    image.src = loadEvent.target.result;
    that.cropper.setImage(image);
  };
 myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the [**documentation**](https://github.com/cstefanache/angular2-img-cropper#user-content-customizing-image-cropper) (that you should read while focused, instead of just reading it on the fly), you can handle the file upload on your own.

This means that you can upload a file, create 2 base64 images, and affect them to the corresponding croppers (or do whatever you want with it.

But I don't understand your issue, because once the image is uploaded, you can simply use the same source and resize the picture to your convenience.
The cropper will create a new image, so it won't alter the base64 source.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Before this requirement I used a script that created a 500x500 and a 300x300 image immediately based on a file from a HTML input. This worked fine and I have my own code to upload to firebase. However, this new requirement means that I need to include ng-img-cropper to allow the user to select the part of the image they want. Currently, with my code, I can only upload the image with cropperSettings1. Ideally I'd like to upload both but cannot find a way for the src file to adopt both settings. Going by your comment, how would one resize the image again after up upload?

Comment: What do you mean by "resize the image again after upload" ? From what I understood, you let the user crop the image, and send both the cropped and non cropped images to firebase. Isn't this your work flow ?

Comment: ah. Apologies if i didn't articulate that very well. I have a HTML input. When the user selects an image (that could be 3000 x 2320 for eg), the image cropper tool will appear and allow the user to select the portion of the image that they want to display. I have a save button that will then upload the cropped image to firebase. However, the cropped image will be 500x500. I want to upload two images. 500x500 and 200x200 but both using the portion of the image the user selected. Right now, I'm only able to upload the 500x500 one. Does that help at all?

Comment: Yes, it's clearer, thank you ! I suggest you only store the 500x500 image, as you're just duplicating data. Store the largest one, and when you want to display it, simply resize it with standard HTML (Trust me, once you see the firebase prices, you'll thank me)

Comment: Unfortunately this is a requirement. In the future, the large image may be 1000x1000 which is used for more heavily designed pages whilst the 200x200 is used for thumbnail roll ups. Otherwise I may have 200 items loaded, all loading a 1000x1000 "thumbnail".

Comment: Then in the future only store the 1000x1000 image ? Anyways, that's your request, so if you want to resize an image, create an HTML image element with `const thumbnail = new Image();`, set the size of it, then convert it to base64.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171325/discussion-between-etx-and-trichetriche).